# Cannot display html in webview

Tags: react-native, webview

I cannot display `html` in my `WebView`:

```
  const titleHtml = '<h1>' +
                     title +
                     '</h1>';

       return
         <WebView 
                style={{
                width: 100,
                height: 100
            }}
            source={{ html: titleHtml }} 
        />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to set the width & height

Comment: Tried that still nothing

Comment: Note that using static html will require setting of originWhitelist to something like "*", have you done that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, WebView, Platform} from 'react-native';

export default class MainActivity extends Component {

     render() {

      var HtmlCode = '<h1> h1 Heading Tag</h1>' +
                     '<p> Sample Paragraph Tag </p>'
                      ;

       return (

         <WebView 

         javaScriptEnabled={true}
         domStorageEnabled={true}
         source={{ html: HtmlCode }}
         />

       );
     }
   }
```

You can run it online [here](https://snack.expo.io/S1t5P2Uw7), it works..

Comment: click the given link

Comment: This code is fine and working .@Bomber Check your logs and try to close package manager and then run again.

Answer (score 0):

We use this package in our project

> https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html

and it works like a charm. There are a few others out there which do a wonderful job